# Youtube Analytics API Demographics as Raw Count (Not Percentage)

Tags: youtube-api, analytics

Does anyone know of a way to get view counts broken down by demographic (age/gender) for a for video and/or a channel?

The YouTube Analytics API is only providing that breakdown by percentage (of logged in users), which is great, but our for our requirements, we need the raw counts. And unfortunately, we can't accurately derive the raw counts from the percentage because the api does not seem to give us the number of logged in users, or enough precision.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't believe that we make those raw counts available on either the web interface or the API—I just checked the web interface and it only shows percentages as well. Feel free to file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29) and I'll see if there's any chance that we could start exposing more details.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - I went ahead and submitted the feature request. Hopefully it this wouldn't be too big of a change to implement.